# Is there a Pythonic way to add a string to the start of each file in a directory made with the name of the file without its extension?

Tags: python-3.7

I have written a code to append a string which is made up of file name to the file with that file name, but it does not append just one line, but the name of all the files in that folder and the line gets added after the data in all the files. All I want is to append a string to the start of the file.

With my code, I am getting all the Three Lines printed in all the files, at the end of each file i.e.

```
  previous data...
  parent a A B C D 
  parent b A B C D 
  parent c A B C D
```

This is my code

```
 import os
 import glob
 os.chdir("C://Users//folder_naming_test_python//")
 files = os.listdir()
 #print("files=" )
 #print(files)
 d = []
 for k in os.listdir():
    d.append( k.split('.')[0])
    #print("names=")
    #print(d)
     prefix = 'parent '
     postfix = ' A B C D'
     Headers = list(map(lambda orig_string :prefix + orig_string + postfix, d))
    #print("Headers = ")
    #print(Headers)
 array_len = len(Headers)
 for file in files:
     for i in range(array_len):
        f = open(file, 'a+')
        a = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(Headers[i]+'\n')
        f.close()
        f = open(file, 'r')
        print(f.read())
```

My input data example would say; 3 files in a folder with names

```
   a.txt, b.txt, c.txt
```

what I expect is irrespective of the data in the files,

```
 either
 parent a A B C D or
 parent b A B C D or
 parent c A B C D 
 followed by the data in file.....
```

has to be printed on first line of each file respectively(Note. a, b and c strings have to go in individual files and not all together in all the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done very easily using [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
for filename in os.listdir():
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
       content = f.read()
       f.seek(0, 0)
       f.write(f"parent {Path(filename).stem} A B C D\n")
       f.write(content)
```

Comment: Thank you cider, for helping but this gives me the file extension in the string as well, is there something, you could suggest me to take off the .txt at the end of filename ?

Comment: Oh, did not figure out that's what you are trying to do. Edited my answer.